# nesting context menus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, right-click, contextmenustrip

I'm trying to add a right click menu to a ToolStripMenuItem but I'm unsure how to do that.

The application I've inherited creates is a system tray application that creates and displays a ContextMenuStrip with ToolStripMenuItems in it on the fly based on input from an xml file. So what I'd like to do is add a right-click menu option to each ToolStripMenuItem in the ContextMenuStrip. Is there an easy way to do this? The only way I can think of is to create a form and display it at the cursor location on a right-click event to the ToolStripMenuItem, but that means i'd have to write all the menu highlighting/selection functionality in to the form myself or add some clunky buttons to the form that do what I want.

Comment: The native Windows menus [actually support this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/04/10252869.aspx). I suspect that the goofy looking `ContextMenuStrip` control (and equivalents) written in C# don't support it; it's fairly uncommon to ever need such a feature. My suggestion would be to switch to using the [`ContextMenu` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) instead, which is a .NET wrapper over the native Windows menus. Not only will they *look* better, you won't miss out on this feature or have to write the code yourself.

Comment: I am using ContextMenu but not sure how to nest menuItems in it.
  public ContextMenu(MenuItem[] menuItems);